# Unable to print the exact line being executed in groovy - GroovyShell?

Tags: groovy

The main groovy file (`MainApp.groovy`) has the following code which invokes `sample.groovy`

```
script = new GroovyShell(binding).parse(new File("sample.groovy))
script.run()
```

`Log4j.xml` has a CONSOLE appender with conversion pattern `%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n`.

Even by changing to different patterns the line number of the groovy file `sample.groovy` is not being printed during execution of methods in `sample.groovy`.

can someone please help me on how to print the lines which is being executed in sample.groovy?

instead of

> 12:40:57,255 DEBUG [sample] Request:

not it is being printed as

> 12:40:57,255 DEBUG [MainApp] Request:

so it is being difficult to debug or to know which line is being executed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking & without seeing the rest of your code, Log4j seems to be able to categorize this well.

In MainApp.groovy

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainApp)
logger.debug("Request ${request}")
```

In sample.groovy:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleApp)
logger.debug("Request ${request}")
```

And you should see output similar to:

```
2015-04-03 15:38:53,649 DEBUG  com.sample.MainApp - Request: REQUEST
2015-04-03 15:38:53,971 DEBUG  com.sample.SampleApp - Request: REQUEST
```